# Checking if remote Akka actor is available

Tags: scala, akka

How can I check if a remote actor, for which I have obtained an actorRef via actorFor, is alive?  Any reference to documentation would be appreciated.  I am using Akka from Scala.

I've seen reference to supervisors and deathwatch, but don't really feel my use-case needs such heavy machinery.  I just want to have my client check if the master is up using a known path, and if it is send a message introducing itself.  If the master is not up, then it should wait for a bit then retry.

**Update 2:**
Suggestions are that I just use a ping-pong ask test to see if it's alive.  I understand this to be something like

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
val future = actor ? AreYouAlive
try{
    Await.result(future, timeout.duration)
}catch{
    case e:AskTimeoutException => println("It's not there: "+e)
}
```

I think I've been confused by the presence of exceptions in the logs, which remain there now.  E.g.

- Error: java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused
- Error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException:null

Perhaps this is just how it works and I must accept the errors/warning in the logs rather than try to protect against them?

Comment: What about simply sending `Ping` message to actor (of course it has to handle it) and wait for `Pong` for some time?

Comment: Good question, have added update.

Comment: No, you should not expect `tell`/`!` operations to throw an exception because handling of the message happens asynchronously. Instead you should send a `Ping` and **wait** for `Pong` for some time. In your remote actor simply add: `case _: Ping => sender ! Pong` and in local one: `remoteActor ? Ping`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just send it messages. Its machine could become unreachable the nanosecond after you sent your message anyway. IF you don't get any reply, it is most likely dead. There's a large chapter on this in the docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/general/message-send-semantics.html

Comment: Thanks.  I think I get it now.  Just confused about there still being errors in the log, but perhaps this is normal (updated question).

Comment: Yes, Akka logs all network errors. You can wire your own logger to disregard those if you want to.

Comment: Viktor, I really want to register a custom handler, say one which returns the message to the sender. Logging vast amounts of crap but not letting me know that there was an error is a difficult scheme to appreciate.

Comment: You'll need to read the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/remoting.html#Remote_Events

Answer (score 1):

You should never assume that the network is available. Our architect here always says that there are two key concepts that come into play in distributed system design.

They are:

- Timeout
- Retry

Messages should 'timeout' if they don't make it after x period of time and then you can retry the message. With timeout you don't have to worry about the specific error - only that message response has failed. For high levels of availability you may want to consider using tools such as zookeeper to handle clustering/availability monitoring. See leader election here for example: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html